# Corrupted Hive tables can't be dropped

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have an issue with two tables that I created in Hive.  I created the two tables using

CREATE TABLE table LIKE other_table;

and then attempted to alter the storage format to ORC using

ALTER TABLE table SET FILEFORMAT ORC;

This apparently corrupted the tables as they now throw an error of table not found whenever they are accessed.  However, they still show up in a with a show tables; statement.  Now, I can't drop the tables or create new ones with the same name.  Here is the direct output from Hive CLI:

```
hive> show tables;
OK
bk_new_profile_events
bk_new_profiles
Time taken: 0.245 seconds, Fetched: 19 row(s)
hive> drop table bk_new_profiles;
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Table not found bk_new_profiles
hive> drop table bk_new_profile_events;
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Table not found bk_new_profile_events
hive>
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete the directory manually of the table with hdfs command :

hdfs dfs -rm -r the/path/to/the/table

(care with -r)